# Dropbox API files pagination in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, dropbox, dropbox-api

I want to paginate Dropbox API files pagination in C#.To populate the Dropbox uploaded files I'm using the following code-

```
RequestResult strReq = OAuthUtility.Get
               (
                 "https://api.dropbox.com/1/metadata/auto/",
                 new HttpParameterCollection
        {
          { "path", "Path" },
          { "access_token", "AccessToken" }
        }

               );
```

Suppose there are 100 files in my account.
How could I paginate the files like 10 records for each page?

Thanks in advance

Comment: but obvious you have to do it manually.

Comment: Could you please tell me the way to pass page Number and page size in Dropbox api request parameter. @Pranav Patel

Comment: unfortunately, dropbox doesn't provide it. for more reference https://www.dropboxforum.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/201862365-Does-the-search-API-supports-pagination-

Comment: Thanks. So the API does not support pagination.Any suggestion how should I approach pagination manually?

Comment: @PranavPatel That forum post is about the search API, but it so happens that `/metadata` also has no support for pagination.